# Subconsulta SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite

Buen día,

Explico mi situación:

-Tengo una tabla llamada "UserProfile", donde una de sus columnas llamada Puesto almacena el ID del puesto del usuario.
-Este puesto se almacena en una tabla llamada "Puestos" el cual está conformada por las columnas IdPuesto y Puesto.

El problema que tengo es el siguiente: tengo una tabla llamada Tareas, donde existe un ASIGNADOR, CONTROLADOR Y REALIZADOR, lo que quiero lograr es obtener el Puesto de cada uno de estos 03 sujetos para así poder filtrarlo posteriormente.

Anexo la consulta SQL que tengo del módulo de tareas:

```
select t.IdTareas
     , t.Asunto
     , t.IdContacto
     , cont.fld_Nomb_Apel_Razon_Social AS 'Contacto'
     , t.AsignadoPor
     , UserProfileAsignador.UserName AS 'Asignador'
     , UserProfileAsignador.Puesto AS 'PAsignador'
     , t.ControladaPor
     , UserProfileAsignadoPor.UserName AS 'Controlador'
     , UserProfileAsignadoPor.Puesto AS 'PControlador'
     , t.AsignadaA
     , UserProfileAsignadaA.userName AS 'Realizador'
     , UserProfileAsignadaA.Puesto AS 'PRealizador'
     , t.FechaAsignacion
     , t.FechaDeVencimiento
     , t.FechaCambioDeEstado
     , t.Observaciones
     , t.Estado AS 'IdTarea'
     , et.Estado AS 'Estado'
     , Confidencial
       from gestionDeTareas.dbo.Tareas AS t
                 left outer join gestionDeTareas.dbo.EstadoDeTareas AS et on t.Estado = et.IdEstadosDeTareas
                 left outer join bd_gestion_de_tareas_config.dbo.vi_list_contactos AS cont on t.IdContacto = cont.IdContacto
                 left outer join gestionDeTareas.dbo.UserProfile AS UserProfileAsignador on t.AsignadoPor = UserProfileAsignador.UserId
                 left outer join gestionDeTareas.dbo.UserProfile AS UserProfileAsignadoPor on t.ControladaPor = UserProfileAsignadoPor.UserId
                 left outer join gestionDeTareas.dbo.UserProfile AS UserProfileAsignadaA on t.AsignadaA = UserProfileAsignadaA.UserId
                 left outer join gestionDeTareas.dbo.Puestos AS Puestos1 on UserProfileAsignador.Puesto = Puestos1.IdPuesto
                 left outer join gestionDeTareas.dbo.Puestos AS Puestos2 on UserProfileAsignadoPor.Puesto = Puestos2.IdPuesto
                 left outer join gestionDeTareas.dbo.Puestos AS Puestos3 on UserProfileAsignadaA.Puesto = Puestos3.IdPuesto
       WHERE 
            t.AsignadoPor = '1' or t.ControladaPor = '1'
       Order by IdTareas ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero, es que si tienes los conjuntos agregados a la query tipo Asignador, AsignadorPor y AsignadoA, para que realizas subconsultas a buscar el nombre. Eso ya lo tienes, con mencionar su alias de tabla.Username

```
select t.IdTareas
     , t.Asunto
     , t.IdContacto
     , cont.fld_Nomb_Apel_Razon_Social as Contacto
     , t.AsignadoPor
     , UserProfileAsignador.UserName AS 'Asignador'
     , t.ControladaPor
     , UserProfileAsignadoPor.UserName AS 'Controlador'
     , t.AsignadaA
     , UserProfileAsignadaA.userName AS 'Realizador'
     , t.FechaAsignacion
     , t.FechaDeVencimiento
     , t.FechaCambioDeEstado
     , t.Observaciones
     , t.Estado as EstadoTarea
     , et.Estado as EstadoDetalle
     , t.IdPuesto
     , Puestos.Puesto
     , Confidencial
       from gestionDeTareas.dbo.Tareas AS t
                 left outer join gestionDeTareas.dbo.EstadoDeTareas AS et on t.Estado = et.IdEstadosDeTareas
                 left outer join bd_gestion_de_tareas_config.dbo.vi_list_contactos AS cont on t.IdContacto = cont.IdContacto
                 left outer join gestionDeTareas.dbo.UserProfile AS UserProfileAsignador on t.AsignadoPor = UserProfileAsignador.UserId
                 left outer join gestionDeTareas.dbo.UserProfile AS UserProfileAsignadoPor on t.ControladaPor = UserProfileAsignadoPor.UserId
                 left outer join gestionDeTareas.dbo.UserProfile AS UserProfileAsignadaA on t.AsignadaA = UserProfileAsignadaA.UserId
                 left outer join gestionDeTareas.dbo.Puestos AS Puestos  on t.IdPuesto = Puestos.IdPuesto
                 left outer join gestionDeTareas.dbo.Puestos AS Puestos2 on UserProfileAsignador.IdPuesto = Puestos.IdPuesto
                 left outer join gestionDeTareas.dbo.Puestos AS Puestos3 on UserProfileAsignadoPor.IdPuesto = Puestos.IdPuesto
                 left outer join gestionDeTareas.dbo.Puestos AS Puestos3 on UserProfileAsignadaA.IdPuesto = Puestos.IdPuesto
       WHERE 
            t.AsignadoPor = @ASIGNADOR or t.ControladaPor = @CONTROLADOR
       Order by IdTareas ASC;
```

Los nombres de los conjuntos son un poco confusos, pero una vez los tienes asignados, sólo tienes que realizar una lectura de cada tabla Puestos con cada tabla UserProfile.

Comment: Solucionado, modifiqué tu consulta de la siguiente forma y ahora si tengo los puestos correspondientes.